# Map Multiple Values to Python Dictionary Key from Two Different Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a user list
`userList = [Bob, Sam, Sue, Jen]`

Each user has specific permissions that return from passing their name into another function. For example, Bob has read access, while every one else has read and write access.

When I pass Bob's name into my permission function, the result returns a list with his permission, Ex: permission('Bob') returns:
`['Read']`

While permission('Sue') returns:
`['Read', 'Write']`

What is the best way to create a dictionary that takes each name as a key and maps each permission as a list of values for that key.  Output expected would be {'Bob':['Read'], 'Sam':['Read', 'Write'], 'Sue':['Read', 'Write'], 'Jen':['Read', 'Write']}

I'm thinking something like:

```
d = {}
for i in userList:
      permissions = permission(i)
```

This is all I have so far so was hoping someone might have a += solution or something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your `permission` function already exist? if so, why not use it as is?

Comment: `dict(zip(userList, map(permission, userList)))`?

Comment: @enke the permission function already exists but it doesn't return the user name with it.  Just the permissions?  So trying to figure out how to get the user mapped to the permissions.  Paul I think that is what I need but the permission function takes in the user name?  Would it need to be in some sort of loop?

Comment: @acodejdatam That single snippet will construct your entire dictionary. `map` takes the names from `userList` and passes them into `permission`, then yields the corresponding result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanna elaborate on my comment with an example, which hopefully illuminates the usage:

```
names = ["bob", "sarah", "john"]

def get_length_squared(name):
    return len(name) ** 2

mapping = dict(zip(names, map(get_length_squared, names)))

for key, value in mapping.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
bob: 9
sarah: 25
john: 16
>>>
```